# Throw error. How can I fix this? I've tried many things, but I am new to it and the logic is a little beyond me

Tags: java, exception, throw

The line with "private static BufferedReader" is where the problem lies. 
"-unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" is the error.
Here is my current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PG2ERC
{    
    private static ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pageRefString.txt"));
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        String [] arr; 
        int n1 = 3;
        int n2 = 4; 
        int f;
        int pf1 = 0;
        int pf2 = 0;
        arr = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for(String s:arr)
        {
            f=Integer.parseInt(s);
            if(arl.contains(f)) 
            {
                arl.remove(arl.indexOf(f));
                arl.add(f);
            } 
            else if(arl.size() < n1) 
            {
                ++pf1;
                arl.add(f);
            } 
            else 
            {
                arl.remove(0);
                arl.add(f);
                ++pf1;
            }


            f=Integer.parseInt(s);
            if(arl.contains(f)) 
            {
                arl.remove(arl.indexOf(f));
                arl.add(f);
            } 
            else if(arl.size() < n2) 
            {
                ++pf2;
                arl.add(f);
            } 
            else 
            {
                arl.remove(0);
                arl.add(f);
                ++pf2;
            }
            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("pg2out.txt"))))
            {
                writer.write(("Number of page faults is ") + pf1);
                writer.write(("Number of page faults is ") + pf2);
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Always reduce questions to a [mcve]. In this case, *none* of the code in your main method is relevant. You could demonstrate the whole thing with just a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is more simply demonstrated like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    private static Reader reader = new FileReader("foo.txt");
}
```

The problem is that the static initializer for your class can throw an exception. That's entirely separate to your `main` method.

Now in your case, the simplest solution is to change your *fields* to local variables:

```
// No need to declare FileNotFoundException - it's a subclass of IOException anyway
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pageRefString.txt"));
    ... rest of method as before ...
}
```

At that point, the code that can throw an exception is within a method that declares that those exceptions can be thrown, so it's fine.

If you *do* need to initialize static variables like this, you should do so in a static initializer block:

```
private static BufferedReader br;
static {
    try { 
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pageRefString.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Go bang hard - RuntimeException isn't a checked exception
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `BufferedReader` static variable to null outside the `main` method. and initialize in `main` method will fix the issue.

```
private static BufferedReader br = null; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pageRefString.txt"));
```